# How can I stop raising event in Tkinter?

Tags: python, events, tkinter

I have some code like this

```
from Tkinter import *
master = Tk()
def oval_mouse_click(event):
    print "in oval"
def canvas_mouse_click(event):
    print "in canvas"
w = Canvas(master, width = 800, height = 600)
uid = w.create_oval(390, 290, 410, 310, fill='blue')
w.tag_bind(uid, "<Button-1>", lambda x: oval_mouse_click(x))
w.bind("<Button-1>" , canvas_mouse_click)
w.pack()
mainloop()
```

When I click on Canvas I have "in canvas" message in console.
When I click] on Oval I have two messages "in oval" and "in canvas", but I want to have only first message. Is there any way to stop event raising?

I can do this task with some global flag but I think there should be more natural way for Tkl.

Comment: You found the easiest way already, `return 'break'` does not work for canvas tag bind.

Comment: Related: [Python tkinter: stopping event propagation in text widgets tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066773/python-tkinter-stopping-event-propagation-in-text-widgets-tags/13076458)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python tkinter: stopping event propagation in text widgets tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066773/python-tkinter-stopping-event-propagation-in-text-widgets-tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the simplest example to handle your issue:

```
import Tkinter

def oval_mouse_click(event):
    print "in oval"
    event.widget.tag_click = True

def canvas_mouse_click(event):
    if event.widget.tag_click:
        event.widget.tag_click = False
        return
    print "in canvas"

root = Tkinter.Tk()
canvas = Tkinter.Canvas(width=400, height=300)
oid = canvas.create_oval(400/2-10, 300/2-10, 400/2+10, 300/2+10, fill='blue')
canvas.tag_click = False
canvas.tag_bind(oid, "<Button-1>", oval_mouse_click)
canvas.bind("<Button-1>" , canvas_mouse_click)
canvas.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

There is no other easier way to handle this under `Canvas`.

Answer (score 3):

I have just posted an improved solution on the similar problem there [Python tkinter: stopping event propagation in text widgets tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066773/python-tkinter-stopping-event-propagation-in-text-widgets-tags).

The core idea is the same as presented in the previous solutions: hijack the `Canvas` widget by binding it with the same event sequence as `tag_bind`. The improved solution I came up with **enables now to simulate the expected `return "break"` behaviour of Tk's other bind+callback pairs**. In short:

1. create a wrapper around the wished `callback`, i.e. a callable class instance
2. when the class instance is called, run `callback` and check its result.

   - if the result is `"break"`, temporarily hijack the event propagation: `bind` the `Canvas` widget to the same event bound to `tag_bind`, with an empty callback. Then, after an idle time, `unbind`.
   - if the result is not `"break"`: do nothing, the event will propagate to `Canvas` automatically

The link above lists a full working example with the `Text` widget, but it is immediately transferable to the Canvas widget.