# Use If statement with keyboard event in Tkinter Python

Tags: python, if-statement, tkinter, keyboard-events

I am writing a program in Python on Ubuntu, to import files from a folder then single Left click for Highlight the filename and "Delete" keyboard button for remove that Highlighted file

Single click is working fine,
but when I press delete button, it is not working and start deleting characters of filename which is totally unnecessary.

I am trying to adding multi-functions when I pressed "Delete" button from keyboard?

how do I use "Delete" button with IF... THEN statement in Python?

```
import subprocess,os
from Tkinter import *


def text_click_callback(event):
    # an event to highlight a line when single click is done
    line_no = event.widget.index("@%s,%s linestart" % (event.x, event.y))
    line_end = event.widget.index("%s lineend" % line_no)
    event.widget.tag_remove("highlight", 1.0, "end")
    event.widget.tag_add("highlight", line_no, line_end)
    event.widget.tag_configure("highlight", background="yellow")
    the_text = event.widget.get(line_no, line_end)

    tex.tag_bind(the_text, "<Delete>", lambda event, the_text1 = path+'/'+the_text: os.remove(the_text1))

def viewFile():
    tex.delete('1.0', END)

    for f in os.listdir(path):
        linkname="link-" + f
        tex.insert(END,f + "\n", linkname)
        tex.tag_configure(linkname, foreground="blue", underline=True)
        tex.tag_bind(linkname, "<Button-1>", text_click_callback )    # highlight a line

if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = Tk()
    step = LabelFrame(root,text="FILE MANAGER", font = "Arial 20 bold   italic")
    step.grid(row=1, columnspan=7, sticky='W',padx=100, pady=5, ipadx=130, ipady=25)

    Button(step,    text="ViewFile",        font = "Arial 8 bold    italic",    activebackground="turquoise",   width=30, height=5, command=viewFile).grid      (row= 6, column =3)
    Button(step,    text="Exit",            font = "Arial 8 bold    italic",    activebackground="turquoise",   width=20, height=5, command=root.quit).grid     (row= 6, column =5)

    tex = Text(master=root)                                      # TextBox For Displaying File Information
    scr=Scrollbar(root,orient =VERTICAL,command=tex.yview)
    scr.grid(row=8, column=2, rowspan=15, columnspan=1, sticky=NS)
    tex.grid(row=8, column=1, sticky=E)
    tex.config(yscrollcommand=scr.set,font=('Arial', 8, 'bold', 'italic'))

    global process
    path = os.path.expanduser("/tmp")                   # Define path To play, delete, or rename video

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Perhaps this (http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm) will help you.

Comment: This will be tricky, as tag_bind is insenstive to return "break" to stop even propagation when you press delete.  More [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066773/python-tkinter-stopping-event-propagation-in-text-widgets-tags). I think you should seriously reconsider using listbox instead of text widget. Text widget was not designed for what you want to do. Listbox was.

Comment: I am not good enough to change whole program from TextBox to ListBox good ...  please If you can help me to do that... Thanak You

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `tag_bind`. Use the normal `bind`method. Then, instead of passing the data in, have the bound function query for the selected filename. If your bound function returns the string `"break"`, it will prevent the default binding from working (the reason why characters are being deleted).

It sounds like you would be better off using a listbox widget, if all you are doing is giving the user a list of items to select. It will require a bit less code, and not be subject to other behaviour that the text widget provides which you likely don't want.

Example:

```
def deleteHighlightedFile(event):
    text = event.widget.get("highlight.first", "highlight.last")
    print "selected file:", text
    return "break"
...
tex = Text(master=root)
tex.bind("<Delete>", deleteHighlightedFile)
```