# tkinter messagebox prevents Entry widget from working

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have a program that has a message box to instruct the user. But after I close the message box, I can't enter in the entry widget.
Has anyone got an idea of what could be the problem?

My code:

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import tkinter.messagebox

class Application(Frame):
    """ GUI aplication hoger of lager"""
    def __init__(self,master):
        """Instaleerd het Frame"""
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        rarara=0;aantal=0;max_pogingen=10;ikdenkaan=random.randrange(1,100)
        self.main()

    def welkom(self):
        """Create Widgets voor het spelletje hoger of lager"""
        #Verwelkomingslebels en instructielabels
        msgb=tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("uitleg",
                                         "Welkom bij het spelletje'hoger of lager'.\nIk heb zojuist aan een getal tussen 1 en 100 gedacht.\nJij mag dat getal raden en je hebt 10 pogingen."
                                         )

    def labels(self):
        #ik denk aan label
        Label(self,
              text="Ik denk aan:"
              ).grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)


    def welkgetal(self):
        rarara=Entry(self)
        rarara.grid(row=0, column=1,sticky=W)
        rarara.configure(state="normal")


    def main(self):
        self.welkom()
        self.labels()
        self.welkgetal()

root=Tk()
root.title("Hoger of lager")
root.geometry("350x280+533+244")
app=Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that Tk modal window behave in a really weird way for event handling :

[0] [Python tkinter: stopping event propagation in text widgets tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066773/python-tkinter-stopping-event-propagation-in-text-widgets-tags)

[1]http://tiku.io/questions/3361808/python-tkinter-bind-breaking

The fix :

```
class Application(Frame):
    """ GUI aplication hoger of lager"""
    def __init__(self,master):
        """Instaleerd het Frame"""
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)
        self.grid()
        rarara=0;aantal=0;max_pogingen=10;ikdenkaan=random.randrange(1,100)
        self.main()
        master.after(1, self.welkom)

    def main(self):
        self.labels()
        self.welkgetal()
```

I don't know why, but it works.

Comment: "I don't know why" isn't  very useful. Also, the "weird way for event handling" has nothing to do with modal windows. That being said, your advice to call `self.welkom` via `after` is a good one. The reason it works is that the event loop needs to be running before opening up a modal window. Instead of `after(1...)` you could use `after_idle(...)` which conceptually means "when tkinter initialization has finished and the event loop has started".

Answer (score 0):

I have been struggling for few days trying to figure out this exact issue where entry widget stops working after a messagebox is shown to screen and closed. My setup was python 3.7 with tkinter.tcl version 8.6.8. After so many trials I have finally fixed it by updating my python to version 3.10.2 and tkinter.Tcl to version 8.6.12. Now it seems to be well responsive before and after a messagebox is shown. It seems like this is a bug in tkinter for some reason not working well at those versions so don't hesitate to update