# CTRL + a select all in entry widget tkinter python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, ctrl, tkinter-entry

How I can select all text like block using click+drug left mouse in Entry widget tkinter python.

```
 e1 = tk.Entry(bop, width = 50, font = "Helvetica 13")
 e1.grid(row=1,column=1, padx=15, pady=15)
 e1.bind_class("Entry","<Control-a>", select_all(e1))
```

here is the function of `select_all()`:

```
def select_all(e):
   a = e.select_range(0,tk.END)
```

Comment: `bind` expects function name (callback) - it means without `()` and arguments. You can create function without arguments which uses your function with argements, or use lambda: `bind( ..., lambda:select_all(e1))`

Comment: BTW: `Entry` has method `get()`  to get all text.

Answer (score 10):

There was so many similar examples on SO

```
import tkinter as tk

def callback(event):
    print('e.get():', e.get())
    # or more universal
    print('event.widget.get():', event.widget.get())
    # select text after 50ms
    root.after(50, select_all, event.widget)

def select_all(widget):
    # select text
    widget.select_range(0, 'end')
    # move cursor to the end
    widget.icursor('end')

root = tk.Tk()

e = tk.Entry(root)
e.pack()
e.bind('<Control-a>', callback)

root.mainloop()
```

`bind` expects filename without `()` and arguments (callback). But also `bind` executes this function always with one argument `event` which gives access to entry which executed this function `event.widget` so you can use it with many different entries. And finally `Entry` has `.get()` to get all text.

---

**EDIT:**

Because after releasing keys `<Control-a>` selection is removed so I use `after()` to execute selection after 50ms. It selects all text (but it moves cursor to the beginning) and moves cursor to the end. (see code above)

---

**EDIT:**

Before I couldn't find correct combination with `Release` but it has to be `<Control-KeyRelease-a>` and now it doesn't need `after()`

```
import tkinter as tk

def callback(event):
    print('e.get():', e.get())
    # or more universal
    print('event.widget.get():', event.widget.get())

    # select text
    event.widget.select_range(0, 'end')
    # move cursor to the end
    event.widget.icursor('end')

root = tk.Tk()

e = tk.Entry(root)
e.pack()
e.bind('<Control-KeyRelease-a>', callback)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: While your example is useful, it doesn't fully answer the question. Can you modify your `callback` method to actually do the "select all" functionality?

Comment: I found `<Control-KeyRelease-a>` and now it doesn't need `after()`

Comment: Strange, at least in Tkinter with Python 2.7 I had to do `event.widget.icursor(0)`, that is the beginning, in order to make the selection to work.

Comment: e.get() or event.get()???????

Comment: @Silidrone not `event.get()` but `event.widget.get()`. And you can use both: `e.get()` or `event.widget.get()`. You can access `Entry` directly using `e` , or access it not-directly using `event.widget` (because `e.bind()` sends `e` as `event.widget`). And this way you can assign the same function to many widgets and `event.widget` will use correct widget.

Answer (score 6):

furas' answer is great but still does not work as a perfect analogue of windows Ctrl+A behavior. The event only fires after releasing the 'a' key, but the event should fire on the 'a' key press.

Taking from [Python tkinter: stopping event propagation in text widgets tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13066773/python-tkinter-stopping-event-propagation-in-text-widgets-tags) , stopping the event propagation is what we need. Returning 'break' stops whatever following event is breaking the ctrl+a behavior, and also allows us to shorten our bind to '<Control-A>'

```py
def callback(event):

    # select text
    event.widget.select_range(0, 'end')
    # move cursor to the end
    event.widget.icursor('end')
    #stop propagation
    return 'break'

root = tk.Tk()

e = tk.Entry(root)
e.pack()
e.bind('<Control-a>', callback)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Is it possible to one line-it using lambda?

Comment: I manage to do it and seems to be working. I hope it doesn't introduce some nasty bugs.        `e.bind('<Control-a>', lambda x: e.selection_range(0, 'end') or "break")`

Comment: @Jack I think you should the function itself, because as you can see the callback function is using its parameter arguments to do the job, hence no external dependency, which means you can use it in every other entry widget there is.

Comment: doesnt work when you ctrl + a and then ctrl + v